# ReactJS form validation Swedish Social Security Number

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am not getting how to implement validation in `reactjs` material UI form. I know Regex very well but not getting how to implement validation in the form so that if value not valid, it should through an error message:

This is My component;

```js
    import React from 'react';
    import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
    import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
    import { FormGroup } from '@material-ui/core';



    function App(props) {


      const handleChange = name => event => {
        setValues({ ...values, [name]: event.target.value });
      };

      return (

        <React.Fragment>
                <FormGroup autoComplete="on">
                  <TextField
                    id=""
                    label="SSN"
                    value={values.ssn}
                    onChange={handleChange('ssn')}
                    type="number"
                    name='ssn'
                  />


                  <Button
                    onClick={() => onSubmit()}
                    variant="contained"
                    color="primary"
                  >
                    Save
                  </Button>
                </FormGroup>

        </React.Fragment>

      );
    }

    export default App;
```

Can anyone help me with how to validate the Swedish social security number?

This is the example of the Swedish social security number: `300728-1243`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to leverage the browser validation you can add a `pattern` attribute to your field, like this:

```html
<input name="sss" type="text" pattern="/^(19|20)?(\d{6}([-+]|\s)\d{4}|(?!19|20)\d{10})$/" />
```

Otherwise, you can custom validate your input with a function, like this:

```js
const sssRegex = /^(19|20)?(\d{6}([-+]|\s)\d{4}|(?!19|20)\d{10})$/

const validateSss = (sss) => sssRegex.test(sss);

console.log(validateSss("195505055555")) // true
console.log(validateSss("19550505-5555")) // true
console.log(validateSss("550505-5555")) // true
console.log(validateSss("550505 5555")) // true
```

Comment: Your check falsely validates for example `190099-0000`

Answer (score 0):

### Swedish SSN

There are two parts to this. First it's the format of the SSN string. Then there is the checksum of the SSN.

### Format

A Swedish SSN consists of the **birth date** encoded in 6 or 8 digits, followed by a hyphen, followed by 4 more number. For example `300728-1243` and `19300728-1243`.

Taking into account the possible values of year, month and day, the matching regex becomes:

`^(19|20)?\d{2}((0[1-9])|(1[012]))(([012][1-9])|(3[01]))-\d{4}$`

### Checksum

The last digit is the checksum and it is calculated from the previous 9 digits (skipping the first 2 for the 12 digit variant).

The checksum is calculated like this:

1. The digits are element-wise multiplicated with 212121-212
2. If any product consists of two digits, its digits are added.
3. The digits are summed.
4. The checksum is the last digit of 10 minus the last digit of the sum.

For example (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_identity_number_(Sweden)#Examples)):

```
811228-987x:

8 * 2 = 16  1 + 6 = 7
1 * 1 =  1          1
1 * 2 =  2          2
2 * 1 =  2          2
2 * 2 =  4          4
8 * 1 =  8          8
9 * 2 = 18  1 + 8 = 9
8 * 1 =  8          8
7 * 2 = 14  1 + 4 = 5

          Sum:     46
Last digit of sum:  6
           10 - 6 = 4 
          Checksum: 4
```

```
670919-953x:

6 * 2 = 12  1 + 2 = 3
7 * 1 =  7          7
0 * 2 =  0          0
9 * 1 =  9          9
1 * 2 =  2          2
9 * 1 =  9          9
9 * 2 = 18  1 + 8 = 9
5 * 1 =  5          5
3 * 2 =  6          6

          Sum:     50
Last digit of sum:  0
          10 - 0 = 10
          Checksum: 0
```

Comment: I know it but how can i implement it in reactjs?